# BadArgumentError: Expected an instance or iterable of (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>); received idofOne (a str)

Tags: google-app-engine

I keep getting the following error :
BadArgumentError: Expected an instance or iterable of (, ); received idofOne (a str).

and have tried to convert to int() but then get a different error saying :
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

What is going on?  I'm using Google App Engine  - and retrieving the idofOne from the html template.  It is the ID representation using jinja -- and it is showing a value of "1" - so it shouldn't be empty - any suggestions???

class makeHeadings3(Handler):

```
def get(self):
    self.render('new_entries/ADMIN_make_headings3.html')

def post(self):
    idofOne = self.request.get("idofOne")

    type2=self.request.get("type2")
    heading2name = self.request.get("headingTwo")
    description2 = self.request.get("descriptionTwo")

    heading3 = self.request.get("headingThree")

    #getting relevant level 1 entry by id 

    level_1_info=Level_1_Headings.get_by_id(idofOne)
```

Actually - I changed the value coming from my template from the id() to the key().  However I'm discovering that in my template from which I'm retrieving the value from is coming back empty string "".  why?  I see the value of the key in teh template and I'm retrieving with the correct name "keyofOne" so why is it coming back empty back to my python server code???
Key for Category Level 1
        DO NOT EDIT

Comment: Please add the html part....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first check:

```
level_1_info=Level_1_Headings.get_by_id("1")
```

Then need to add debug in your code to see what value is returned by "idofOne"

```
import logging
# snip
logging.info("type "+type(idofOne))
logging.info("value "+idofOne)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: great - helpful tip.  I discovered that I'm getting an empty string back from my template.  Here's html from template:               <label for="idofOne">Key for Category Level 1</label>
  <input name="idfOne" value="{{heading1_info.key().id()}}">               and then back to my server code is    def post(self):
  myidofOne = self.request.get("idofOne")
  self.response.out.write(myidofOne)
Any ideas on why I'm getting back an empty string??  Many thanks for even looking at

Comment: @user1769203  <input name="idfOne" value="{{heading1_info.key().id()}}"> I hope you mistyped here idfOne and it's not on your actual code... :-)

Comment: yes - sorry - it was a typo - I have been trying multiple options between getting the key and the id and while it displays it in my html template rendering, the value does not get passed back to server python code

Comment: @user1769203 if the answer was helpful could you please tick the answered box?

Answer (score 1):

The below should fix it. You need to get the integer value of that id

```
idofOne = int(self.request.get("idofOne"))
```

Always when parsing post or get parameters you have to convert them to the correct type before passing them to the datastore query.